# How do you generate a random number that is 12 digits long in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on something in python that involves generating a random number that must be 12 digits long, how would I do this?

For example, every time the program is run, it would generate numbers such as 424476789811, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to the SO-community!

How about using [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) between 10^12 and 10^13 - 1?

```py
import random

print(random.randint(10**12, 10**13 - 1))
# randint is inclusive on both sides, so we need the - 1

# or

print(random.randrange(10**12, 10**13))
# randrange does not include the stop integer
```

Comment: it doesn't work i tried it.

Comment: did you get any particular errors? maybe you are using python2?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `random.randint`:

```
import random
print(random.randint(100000000000, 999999999999))
```

Output:

```
785657835683
```

This gets a random number between `100000000000` and `999999999999`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get random integer having 12 digits long length and you can its range. Hope it will works for you.Peace!

```
import random

print(random.randint(1**12, 10**12))

#returns a number between 1 and 9, you can change the range of number by changing 1 and 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several ways to accomplish this but it all depends on how you want your numbers to be generated. Python's `numpy` library has a module random which you can use to generate a random number between 0 and 1 (1 not included) with equal probability. i.e. samples of the uniform distribution: [`numpy.random.rand()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy-random-rand)

One way to do it would be to take that number you generate and map it from a domain of `0-1` to a domain of `10**11` to `10**12`. Keep in mind that although the latter is a 13 digit number the upper bound is not included!

The linear mapping would thus be the line going through the points `(0, 1e11)` and `(1, 1e12)`. Can you come up with the equation of that line?

Some things to keep in mind:

1. The data type in this case is of paramount importance: using `float32` is not enough for the precision required and so your datatype should be `numpy.float64`.
2. Your numbers will be in that range but won't be rounded, so you should use floor to round them (and exclude the top).